# Who can tell me the difference between assignment and copy of the NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

1.Assignment

```
NSArray* a = xxxxxx;

NSArray* b;

b = a;
```

2.Copy

```
NSArray* a = xxxxxx;

NSArray* b;

b = [a copy];
```

I know copy is "light copy",mutable copy is "deep copy".

copy is copy memory address,and mutable copy is copy memory objects.

But i don't know assignment and copy's different.

It's the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW1) Apple documentation is helpful:

> The normal copy is a shallow copy that produces a new collection that
>   shares ownership of the objects with the original. Deep copies create
>   new objects from the originals and add those to the new collection.

Therefore, in your first example, `b` points to the same NSArray instance as `a`. In the second example, `b` points to a new instance of NSArray containing references to the same objects contained in the array pointed to by `a`.

Comment: I have another question.if i use the copy,i change b's data,the a's data will change too?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'change b's data'. If you remove the object from a (you would need to use NSMutableArray for this, then no, no change to b (since b retains the object). If you change a property of an object in a, then you will see that change in the same object in b.

Answer (score 0):

`b = a;`  `b` is pointing the same address where `a` points. So changing either one will be same. This is called like `call by reference`.

`b = [a copy];` is creating another object of `a` and that is pointed by `b`. Here two different sets of objects are formed, so changing either one will be independent of each other. This is like `call by value`. And here `b` will hold an immutableCopy of `a`, even if `a` was mutable.

Comment: This is actually incorrect - the first is not a shallow copy, just assigning `b` to point to the same object as `a`. The second is a shallow copy.